# Problems with JSONP and Github API v3

Tags: javascript, jsonp, github-api

I'm trying to access the Github API with Javascript and I'm having some trouble when handling the access_token response.
Here's my `callback.html` code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var code = window.location.search.substring(6);
var cb = function(data) {
    console.log(data);
}

var scriptTag = document.createElement("SCRIPT");
scriptTag.src = "https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token?client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID&client_secret=MY_CLIENT_SECRET&code="+code+"&format=json&callback=cb";
document.getElementsByTagName('HEAD')[0].appendChild(scriptTag);
</script>
```

I got this error on Chrome:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

I got this error Firefox:

```
SyntaxError: invalid label
```

If I manually open the link I can see that github response is correct:

```
{"access_token":"*********","token_type":"bearer"}
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Your script source is wrong. It should be:

```
scriptTag.src = "https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token?client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID&client_secret=MY_CLIENT_SECRET&code="+code+"&format=json&callback=cb";
```

Previously you only had `https:github.com` instead of `https://github.com`

Comment: Wow, you're right. I don't think that's relevant though, because I'm still getting the error.